# Rstudio running very slow on PopOS Surface Go 2

Tags: rstudio

I've recently got into Linux (and really like it!) but my RStudio runs extremely slow even when no packages are loaded (just basic interactions).

I've done the usual trouble shooting techniques of turning off saving .RData and ensuring the graphics using Software as Rendering Engine.

Any other advice?

My RStudio version is

```
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01) -- "Bird Hippie"
Copyright (C) 2021 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

and my linux version is (uname -a)

```
Linux linux 5.19.0-76051900-generic #202207312230~1660780566~22.04~9d60db1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu A x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem...even navigating to check version is painfully slow. Extreme..

RStudio 2022.07.1 Build 554
"Spotted Wakerobin" Release (7872775e, 2022-07-22) for Ubuntu Jammy

Linux pop-os 5.19.0-76051900-generic #202207312230~1660780566~22.04~9d60db1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu A x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux